# Rotating parcel in Parcel Fabric?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, rotate, parcel-fabric

I am working in ArcMap wanting to rotate a parcel in parcel fabric.

NOT working in parcel fabric you can click "S" for another rotating point to come up.

However this does not work in parcel fabric. I can rotate the parcel, however its not letting me create another rotate point

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please always tag questions about using a Parcel Fabric in ArcMap with at least the [tag:parcel-fabric] and [tag:arcmap] tags.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible with the rotation tool in the Transform Parcels toolbar. You're able to move the rotation point to another vertex by clicking and dragging, but not add another.

[image: Transform Parcels Rotate Tool]